# How to run JUnit tests from the command line if classes are in packages?

Tags: java, junit, illegalargumentexception, classnotfound, junit-runner

The class `ParserTest` is in the package `myproject.tests` and stored in this directory structure:

```
.
└── myproject
    └── tests
        └── ParserTest.class
```

Set the CLASSPATH for the current shell session (no `-cp` option, to keep to java call clean):

```
export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/lib/java/junit-4.12.jar:/usr/local/lib/java/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

Call the JUnit runner and pass the test class as the argument:

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore myproject/tests/ParserTest
```

This error gets thrown:

```
...
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [myproject/tests/ParserTest]
...
```

Comment: It took me some time to figure that out and because I have not found anything on StackExchange (with my searchterms), I wrote this Q/A to help people that face the same problem and use the same lingo to search for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` requires the argument to use `.` as a separator between directories and classes, instead of `/`.

The calltrace looks like that and ends in `java.lang.Class.forName(classname)`:

```
JUnitCore.main(args)
└── JUnitCore.runMain(args)
    └── JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(args)
        └── new JUnitCommandLineParseResult().parseArgs(args);
            └── JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(...);
                └── ...
                    └── org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(arg);
                        └── java.lang.Class.forName(className);
```

The JavaDoc for `java.lang.Class.forName(String className)` says:

> Parameters: className - **the fully qualified name** of the desired class.

And in Java, fully qualified names are written with `.` not `/`.